# How to overload polymorphic == and != operator in c++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, operator-overloading, overloading

```
class Media {
public:
    bool operator==(const Media& other) const {}
    bool operator!=(const Media& other) const {}
};

class Book : public Media {
public:
    bool operator==(const Book& other) const {} // commenting out this line solves this issue.
    bool operator!=(const Book& other) const {}
};

class Game : public Media {
public:
    bool operator==(const Game& other) const {}
    bool operator!=(const Game& other) const {}
};

int main() {
    Book book;
    Game game;

    bool res = book == game;  // doesn't compile.
}
```

I have these 3 classes and they *must have* their own == and != operators defined. But then I also have to compare between two siblings using those operators.

I could've written a (pure) virtual function, say, `virtual bool equals(const Media& other) const` in the base class that subclasses override. And then call that function in the bodies of == and != opertor definition in base class `Media`. But that feature is gone when I add another `bool operator==(const Book& other) const {}` in the `Book` class (the same goes for the `Game` class too).

Now I want to compare between siblings using those operators and still have all 6 definition in those 3 classes. How do I make it work?

Comment: Do you want to use the `Media::operator==(const Media&)` operator when you compare `Book` and `Game`?

Comment: You have 3*3 combinations (for `==`), which are your expected results?

Comment: [Double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++)

Comment: If it is comparable in that way then the comparison should be done on Media class. What I mean is that if you look at them purely as Media then you should be able to compare them hence just implement the Media == and != operators.

Comment: Notice than polymorphic `equals` has several pitfall, see [Java equals](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/12sp/homework/6/ch3_effectivejava-excerpt.pdf), especially, symmetry and transitivity concern.

Comment: I think the most important question to ask is _why_ do you want to compare different types like this? If different media should be symmetrically equatable, then it should be possible to compare from only the knowledge that the base-class has of the information -- _not_ the children. If you've designed yourself into a corner where this is the only way out, then it's a strong smell that there are problems with this design.

Comment: ```Media``` essentially can be an abstract class. I want to compare between two ```Game``` or two ```Book``` or a ```Game``` and a ```Book``` or a ```Book``` and a ```Game```. They should be able to be compared directly like ```game == book``` (result should be ```false```) or they can be compared using ```Media*``` or ```Media&```

Comment: @Human-Compiler you caught me. Those are the mentioned restriction. Is there a way out of this? Without commenting out the definitions in the child classes?

Comment: @Jarod42 ```Media``` essentially can be an abstract class. I want to compare between two ```Game``` or two ```Book``` or a ```Game``` and a ```Book``` or a ```Book``` and a ```Game```. They should be able to be compared directly like ```game == book``` (result should be ```false```) or they can be compared using ```Media*``` or ```Media&```

Comment: @roniabusayeed Then you should use Media in all cases. Not Game and not Book. `other` is always a `const Media&`

Comment: @roniabusayeed not sure why comment out `Book::operator==` works? you still cannot correctly compare `Book` and `Game`. as it would call `Media::operator==`

Comment: and what "But that feature is gone" means? does it mean you cannot change `Game` and `Media` in any way?

Comment: Add `using Media::operator==;` in Book and Game, so that the base operator can participate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that this form of comparison is an imposed restriction (to compare among siblings of a child type). If its an imposed restriction that you need to somehow perform this with *inheritance*, then one option is to fulfill the base signature and use `dynamic_cast`. Note that this is not a *clean* approach, but it might be the expected solution for this problem if this is some form of assignment.

`dynamic_cast` uses Runtime Type Information (RTTI) to determine whether an instance to a base class is actually an instance of the derived class. When you use it with a pointer argument, it returns `nullptr` on failure -- which is easily testable:

```cpp
auto p = dynamic_cast<const Book*>(&other);
if (p == nullptr) { // other is not a book
  return false;
}
// compare books
```

You can use this along with a `virtual` function to satisfy the hierarchy. However, to avoid possible ambiguities with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)'s generated symmetric `operator==`/`operator!=` functions, it's usually better to do this through a *named* `virtual` function rather than the `operator==` itself in order to prevent ambiguity:

```cpp
class Media {
public:
  virtual ~Media() = default;

  bool operator==(const Media& other) const { return do_equals(other); }

private:
  virtual bool do_equals(const Media& other) const = 0;
};

class Book : public Media {
  ...
private:
  bool do_equals(const Media& other) const override {
    auto* p = dynamic_cast<const Book*>(&other);
    if (p == nullptr) { return false; }

    return (... some comparison logic ...);
  }
  ...
};

... Same with Game ...
```

Since we never define `operator==(const Book&)` or `operator==(const Game&)`, we won't see this shadow the base-class' `operator==`; instead it always dispatches through the base's `operator==(const Media&)` -- which is non-`virtual` and prevents ambiguity.

This would allow a `Book` and a `Game` to be comparable, but to return `false` -- whereas two `Book` or two `Game` objects may be compared with the appropriate logic.

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/EK6K4vhae)</kbd>

---

## *That said...*

This approach is not a good design, as far as software architecture goes. It requires the derived class to query what the type is -- and usually by the time you need to do this, that's an indication that the logic is funky. And when it comes to equality operators, it also leads to complications with symmetry -- where a different derived class may choose to compare things weirdly with different types (imagine a `Media` that may compare `true` with other different media; at which point, the order matters for the function call).

A better approach in general is to define *each* of the respective equality operators between any types that logically require equality comparison. If you are in C++20 this is simple with symmetric equality generation; but pre-C++20 is a bit of a pain.

If a `Book` is meant to be comparable to a `Game`, then define `operator==(const Game&)` or `operator==(const Book&, const Game&)`. Yes, this may mean you have a large number of `operator==`s to define for each of them; but its much more coherent, and can get better symmetry (especially with C++20's symmetric equality):

```cpp
bool operator==(const Game&, const Book&);
bool operator==(const Book&, const Game&); // Generated in C++20
bool operator==(const Game&, const Game&);
bool operator==(const Book&, const Book&);
```

In an organization like this, `Media` may not even be logical as a 'Base class'. It may be more reasonable to consider some form of static polymorphism instead, such as using `std::variant` -- which is touched on in @Jarod42's answer. This would allow the types to be homogeneously stored and compared, but without requiring casting from the base to the derived type:

```cpp
// no inheritance:
class Book { ... };
class Game { ... };

struct EqualityVisitor {
  // Compare media of the same type
  template <typename T>
  bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return lhs == rhs; }

  // Don't compare different media
  template <typename T, typename U>
  bool operator()(const T&, const U&) const { return false; }
};

class Media
{
public:
  ...

  bool operator==(const Media& other) const {
    return std::visit(EqualityVisitor{}, m_media, other.m_media);
  }
private:
  std::variant<Book, Game> m_media;
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/eEWM4vfGz)</kbd>

This would be my recommended approach, provided the forms of media are meant to be fixed and not extended.

Answer (score 0):

You might do double dispatch thanks to [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)/[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17):

```
class Media;
class Book;
class Game;

using MediaPtrVariant = std::variant<const Media*, const Book*, const Game*>;

class Media {
public:
    virtual ~Media () = default;
    virtual MediaPtrVariant asVariant() const { return this; }
};

class Book : public Media {
public:
    MediaPtrVariant asVariant() const override { return this; }
};

class Game : public Media {
public:
    MediaPtrVariant asVariant() const override { return this; }
};

struct EqualVisitor
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T*, const T*) const { return true; }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(const T*, const U*) const { return false; }
};


bool operator ==(const Media& lhs, const Media& rhs)
{
    return std::visit(EqualVisitor(), lhs.AsVariant(), rhs.AsVariant());
}

bool operator !=(const Media& lhs, const Media& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

int main()
{
    Book book;
    Game game;

    bool res = book == game;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f84383ee52184760)